# flutter ExpansionPanel header right to left

Tags: flutter

I want to use `ExpansionPanel` with the default clickable icon on the left and the title on the right

and in the below header, I want to use `Divider`

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: I only know about changing header position in ExpansionTile. i.e, by passsing `controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,`. I don't know about ExpansionPanel